# Missing operand error in batch statement with variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm getting a syntax error on the timeout command supposedly because of a "missing operand". But I don't see any operand missing.

```
 rem description for the user to read
 echo Insert time in minutes:
 rem setting default (1 hour)
 set /a timeto=3600
 rem asking user for input (integer)
 set /p timeto=
 rem converting minutes to seconds
 set /a timeto=%timeto%*60
 rem command based on the inputted value
 timeout /t %timeto% /nobreak
```

Comment: you cant set comments in this way.

Comment: I'm very new to batch. How should the comment's be set? (btw, in my file I don't have these comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invalid syntax. Commenting commands inline is not possible in `cmd` CLI nor a batch scripts:

```
==>set /a timeto=3600            ::setting default time (1 hour)
Missing operator.

==>set /a timeto=3600
3600
==>
```

Note that `%timeTo%*60` exceeds `timeout /T` valid range `-1` to `99999` for default `3600*60`.

If your code snippet appears enclosed in `()` parentheses, then use [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

```
@ECHO ON >NUL
@SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
if 1==1 (
  rem description for the user to read
  echo Insert time in minutes:  
  rem setting default time (1 hour = 60 minues)
  set /a timeTo=60            
  rem asking user for input (integer)
  set /p timeTo=                
  rem converting minutes to seconds - erroneous
  set /a timeTo=%timeTo%*60     
  rem converting minutes to seconds - right approach
  set /a timeTo=!timeTo!*60     
  rem command based on the inputted value
  echo timeout /t !timeTo! /nobreak  
)
```

**Output**: note that `set /a timeTo=%timeTo%*60` line causes the `Missing operand` error as results to erroneous `set /a timeTo=*60` in the parse time.

```
==>D:\bat\SO\32410773.bat

==>if 1 == 1 (
rem description for the user to read
 echo Insert time in minutes:
 rem setting default time (1 hour = 60 minues)
 set /a timeTo=60
 rem asking user for input (integer)
 set /p timeTo=
 rem converting minutes to seconds - erroneous
 set /a timeTo=*60
 rem converting minutes to seconds - right approach
 set /a timeTo=!timeTo!*60
 rem command based on the inputted value
 echo timeout /t !timeTo! /nobreak
)
Insert time in minutes:

Missing operand.
timeout /t 3600 /nobreak

==>
```

Comment: I had actually not tested the default (have been testing it with a 2 minute delay - 120, so that must not be the cause of the error). In any case, that is indeed a problem, I'm definetly going to need timeouts longer than one hour. How can I solve that? Is there some wait/sleep statement I can use?

Comment: `set /A timetomax=99999/3600` returns 27, hence max. value for `timeout /T 99999` waits for more than 27 hours...

Comment: I wrote this comment before seeing the edits to your answer and before understanding your solution. I've just started learning the basics of bash a couple hours ago, so I'm still stumbling around and getting startled with all these new concepts. I understood the solution (a bit like using php with html). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Batch does not support inline comments.All comments need to be in separate line:

```
::description for the user to read 
echo Insert time in minutes:
::setting default time (1 hour)  
set /a timeto=3600
::asking user for input (integer)            
set /p timeto=
::converting minutes to seconds                
set /a timeto=%timeto%*60
::command based on the inputted value    
timeout /t %timeto% /nobreak
```

Comment: Corrected it, Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @jony - after your edit... Check also JosefZ answer. You'll need delayed expansion and accessing variables with `!` instead of `%` within brackets blocks.

Comment: Yes, it is all working fine now. I see that REM is another way to comment.